# Edit Top Navigation Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an online store developed in *Wordpress/WooCommerce* and I need to add some flags, in top navigation.

In *header.php* I saw that that section is called by `woo_top()` function, but I don't find it.

Please help me to find this function or how to add some code in top navigation.

Comment: Have a read at the WooCommerce hooks/actions/filters documentation. As far as I recall it's very well documented. Also, please don't put links to your site in your question unless it's absolutely required as it comes across as spammy.

Comment: What do you mean by `some flags`?

Comment: I never mentioned anything about any flags...

Comment: The website will have more languges, and i need to put the flag of the country. Can I add a screenshot with website?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hook In
add_action( 'woo_top', 'woo_bootstrapped_nav' );

// Our hooked in Function
function woo_bootstrapped_nav() { ?>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
               <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
     <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" class="brand"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
            <?php

                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'top-bar',
                    'depth'      => 2,
                    'container'  => 'div',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse pull-left',
                        'menu_class'     => 'nav',
                    'walker'     => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                );

                wp_nav_menu($args);

            ?>

<ul class="nav secondary-nav pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[fblike style="button_count" width="90" float="left"][google_plusone size="medium" float="left" annotation="bubble"][twitter_follow username="twitter_name" show_screen_name="false" count="false" float="left"]'); ?></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } // End woo_bootstrapped_nav()
```

here in above code add flag images below home url link.

Comment: Also, Add do_action to header.php